# Finding user's groups SIDs inside Sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory

I need to find out all AD groups SIDs that current user belongs to inside my Sharepoint (2007) webpart.

I wanted to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, accountName ))
    {
        var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
        ...
    }
}
```

, but I get the following error:

Event ID: 10016
Through the permission settings (application specific) is the SID (S-1-5-20) for user NT AUTHORITY \ NETWORK SERVICE of address localhost (Using LRPC) is not authorized to activate (Local) for the COM Server application with CLSID
{61738644-F196-11D0-9953-00C04FD919C1}

This might be fixed with this  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899965
but this approach requires changing registry values (the ownership of the application, so you can change apps values at dcomcnfg) and later User Permissions at dcomcnfg's COM security, which isn't an option for me.

Is there another way to access Current user's groups SIDs inside Sharepoint?

I really hoped I can find these values in SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Groups, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go the SharePoint way here and not use `System` assemblies, but the SharePoint ones.

The SID of each user is in the [`SPUser.Sid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.sid.aspx) Property. As you want to look for AD groups only you can check the `.IsDomainGroup` Property of `SPUser`.

Now all you need to do is check the current user: ´SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser`(a`SPUser` object).

To answer your question how to get all groups a user belongs to, you actually **will** need to use `System.DirectoryServices`. A solution for your problem is shown in the following stackoverflow posts:

- [In C#, how to access Active Directory to get the list of groups that a certain user belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553623/in-c-how-to-access-active-directory-to-get-the-list-of-groups-that-a-certain-u)
- [Querying AD for finding all groups of a user - Missing one group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470154/querying-ad-for-finding-all-groups-of-a-user-missing-one-group)

So in short: `SPUser` object as well as querying the Active Directory via `DirectoryServices`

Comment: Thanks for the replay. 
For me there's one problem with that solution.
While using System.DirectoryServices I need to provide the username and password of a user that has AD read rights.
Is there a way to access AD with System.DirectoryServices via SharePoint without providing user credentials?
For example using this constructor and leaving username & password fields empty and specifying a certain auth type?
    public DirectoryEntry(string path, string username, string password, AuthenticationTypes authenticationType);

Comment: What's wrong with specifying a user with read rights? You could for example allow the Sharepoint application pool's user to read active directory or create a dedicated user for that.

Comment: Thanks, I also see no other option than providing credentials to DirectoryEntry object.